# How can I simulate microwave radio link transmission?

Tags: simulation, modulation, data, transmission, data-rate

My task is to simulate a two-way data transmission microwave link. The fixed parameters are distance, transmitter power, carrier frequencies, bandwidth, receiver noise figure, intermediate frequency, adjacent channel crosstalk. The variable parameters are data rates, and modulation formats. The task doesn't say anything more, but just to "examine the transmission", but in my opinion, I should check the bit error rate of the links.

I've already tried to simulate this in AWR Design environment (Microwave Office), with the system diagram option, but the problem was that I couldn't adjust the antenna distance. If you know how to add this parameter, or you've already done some simulation in System diagram, please help me.

So, U don't really know **which program should I use for this task**. Maybe Matlab Simulink would be appropriate, but I think it's too general, and it would be circumstantial.

I would be thankful if you could help me with this problem, even if you just tell me which program should I use.

PS: sorry for bad English.
Thanks everyone.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Friis transmission formulas and how to make an antenna more directional?

Comment: Not really, but as I've checked it  on wiki, it's related to antenna gain and effective area, but i don't have to adjust the antennas. I think my task is to analyze BER, or other transmission charachteristics depending on bitrate, and modulation(QAM, QPSK)

Comment: **Tasks do not exist in an information vacum** If this is homework, there will have been relevant information presented during class which gives hints towards the expected course of action.  If this is a professional project, you need to have a conversation with your boss, client, or customer to clarify their rather open ended expectations.